# Are Humans from Reikland all Doomed?

Tags: character-creation, human, wfrp-4e

In the Character Chapter, in Species Skills and Talents, Humans (Reiklander) (p36), the list of talents suggests that you have to choose between some talents.
Here is the way it is written:

> Talents: Doomed, Savvy *or* Suave, 3 Random Talents

When I read this line, I see symmetry that groups the choice: `[Doomed, Savvy, Suave]` and `[3 Random Talents]`.
It made me think that we have to choose between Doomed, Savvy, and Suave. The character Salundra von Drakenburg only has Savvy in the Starter Set Character.
[image]

Comment: In English when a list has at least one entry that itself contains a comma, all entries in that list are then separated by semicolons instead of commas. (For example, *I like cute, little puppies; fresh, slightly melted chocolate ice cream; and bleak, overcast weather.*) So if the intent were a choice between Doomed, Savvy, or Suave, a decent editor would've had that one entry—a lone choice between three things—followed by a semicolon then that other item, the entry *3 random talents.* I have no idea how skilled the editors are on *WFRP*, though.

Comment: @HeyICanChan I think you're already making this point, but this is _not_ a list where at least one entry contains a comma; it has one entry which contains "or". This is what the Oxford comma is for: the absence of a comma before "or" should make it clear that that the two items separated by "or" constitute a single entry in the main list. Sadly, we don't live in a world where the Oxford comma convention can be assumed.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

#### All humans from Reikland are Doomed.

The character sheet you use is made for newcomers (some data isn't written on it in order to keep it as simple as possible). You can find the complete one [here](https://www.drivethrurpg.com/product/285748/Warhammer-Fantasy-Roleplay-Fourth-Edition-Starter-Set-Character-Pack).

All the choices you have to make are between two options.
The Starter set character **Salundra von Drakenburg** is a human from Reikland. She has the talent Doomed and Savvy, and she only was a Scion in the past (now an Officer). Since you cannot take talents not related to your exact carrier (p48), it shouldn't be possible for her to have this talent if not taken as a human.

Thanks to Theik in the comment section, that's also true from a lore perspective:

> "Sometime near their tenth birthday, every child in the Empire should experience the Dooming, a rite of passage that ends with a foretelling of death"

[image: Salundra von Drakenburg portrait description]

[image: Salundra talents list]

Comment: Could you clarify where the conflicting information on the example character from the starter set comes from? The question includes a character sheet which does not show the Doomed talent, but the answer shows a different one that does?

Comment: The character sheet in the question is the one provided in the Starter Set, made for newcomers etc. But you can find the "real" character sheet, with for example the amount of xp spend, all talents and skills, etc. Everything you need if you want to create *this* character with a real character sheet. Is that clear ?

Comment: Yes, I understand now - there’s a simplified one in the box set, and a fully detailed one available on the web site, the latter of which includes the Doomed talent. Thanks!

Comment: I edit my answer in order to clarify this point. If it suit you, then thats ok. If not, do not hesitate to edit it in order to be more precise and explicit :)